# How do I get the new Android Market running on Cyanogen 2.2 HTC Magic?

Tags: google-play-store, cyanogenmod

I'm running Cyanogen 2.2 on my HTC magic.
The Android Market is still the old version and not the one that has been discussed in the news.

http://mashable.com/2010/12/11/new-android-market-coming-soon/

My wife's Samsung Galaxy 5 runs this new version which has stock 2.1.

Does anyone know how I can get the new version running?

Thanks.

Comment: I know that CyanogenMod 7 will include it by default, but it is currently in alpha/testing.

Comment: Doesn't the Market auto-update?

Comment: @Matthew yes, but there is something funky with CM and the market self-updating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some flashable .zip versions floating around, but people seem to have mixed success with them. Generally speaking, installing the .apk in a traditional manner will cause FC issues.

There's [a couple of thread](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/13802-latest-market-and-maps/)s over on the CM forums with links to zips you can try. [Here's one such thread](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/12188-installing-market-v226/) for Market v2.2.6 (the first version with the new style). You might need to do a little hunting if you want the most recent version (2.2.11, I believe).

Some people have also reported success using the latest [MDPI version of gapps](http://goo-inside.me/gapps/) instead of the MDPI-Tiny version, but I'm not sure how likely that is to work.

As with most other modifications, I'd recommend making a NAND/Ti backup before you do this. I flashed a newer Market on my EVO but it caused a bootloop the first time I tried. I think I ultimately ended up clearing my `data/` and `cache/` partitions, then clearing my dalvik-cache, then flashing the new Market. You might not have to do something that excessive to get it to work, but it seemed to do well on my phone.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out. Ideally I was hoping for auto-update of the app but I guess that isn't possible.

Comment: @sickgemini: I don't know if the auto-update works in CM at all, to be honest. My phone's Market has never updated itself...